# Get SSRS report as pure html for c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get SSRS repoert as html to open it on mobile device.
I've added the relevant credentials to the **HttpWebRequest** object and success to get the result if I use the following patten URL:

> http://APPserver.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/APP/APP%20Reports/RequestReport&ReportFormat=expandable&rc:Parameters=false&APPRequestId=c624561c-5f40-4545-8e13-d900c83449a8&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0

---

This format gives me a lot of text but not the pure html that I need, so I've added parameter that clean the report file I got exacly what I need **from browser** but when I'm trying to get it from c# code i got 401 error.

the parameter is:

> &rc:toolbar=false

As following:

> http://APPserver.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/APP/APP%20Reports/RequestReport&ReportFormat=expandable&rc:Parameters=false&APPRequestId=c624561c-5f40-4545-8e13-d900c83449a8&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:toolbar=false

I check this code from hte server himself with the administrator credentials but nothing works from code with this parameter.

Thanks!
Naftali.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to the different between the browser and the code credentials.
Using default network credentials gave me the same credentials as browser client:

```
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

instead of:

```
request.Credentials = request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

apparently using the credentials stracture gives more needed data.

Thanks,
Naftali.